# ASP.net mvc cache output of Html.Partial from Shared folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In *My MVC Shared Folde*r, there is a `Partial View(_Sidebar.cshtml)` which I call from `_Layout.cshtml` using:

```
@Html.Partial("_Sidebar")
```

How do I cache this sidebar partial file & specify cache parameters?

If it was a controller method, I would have decorated it with `[OutputCache(Duration = 10)]` & achieved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `[ChildActionOnly]` controller method which returns you partial view

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 10)]
[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult SideBar()
{
    return PartialView("_SideBar");
}
```

and then in the view use `Html.Action()` or `Html.RenderAction()` to call the method and return the partial.

```
@Html.Action("Sidebar") // or @{ RenderAction("Sidebar"); }
```

Comment: My problem is it is in a shared folder. so probably i have to create another controller & then a method. right ?

Comment: That has got nothing to do with it - `return PartialView("_SideBar");` will return the `_SideBar.cshtml` partial that is in your `/Views/Shared` folder

Comment: In which controller do i create this method ? There are 50+ controllers in my project. & i am calling above partial from _layout.cshtml which is also in shared folder

Comment: It does not really matter. You could put it in say `HomeController` (and then it would be `@Html.Action("Sidebar", "Home")`) - or you could create a separate controller - say `CommonController` (and then it would be `@Html.Action("Sidebar", "Common")`)

Comment: For the record, I created a Partials Controller for such actions.